# Some troubleshoot to writing custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs in my project.

I want to filter my array in ng-repeat.

Here is HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="sensorData in list.sensorsData |
                                filterByAlert:list.alertTags">
        <td>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">{{ sensorData.Area }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is how looks list.sensorsData array of objects:

[image]

Here is how looks list.alertTags array of objects:

[image]

I need to show in ng-repeat elements only list.sensorsData rows that has alertType properties value equal to Id proiperty in list.alertTags.

for this purpose I wrote this filter:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("sensorsData").filter('filterByAlert', filterByAlert);

    function filterByAlert() {
        var result = [];
        return function (sensorRecords, alertTypes) {
            if (!sensorRecords)
                return;
            if (!alertTypes)
                return;
            angular.forEach(sensorRecords, function (sensorRecord, key) {
                angular.forEach(alertTypes, function (alertType, key2) {
                    if (sensorRecord.AlertType == alertType.Id ) {
                        result.push(sensorRecord);
                    }
                })
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
})();
```

but when filter is fired I get this error:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: sensorData in list.sensorsData |
                                    filter:filterByAddress |
                                    orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |
                                    filterByAlert:list.alertTags, Duplicate key: object:8, Duplicate value: {"Id":8,"Address":"125 king g.str","AlertType":3,"Area":"North","MeasureDate":"2012-10-12T16:10:00","MeasureValue":-1}
```

It seems I have problem with logic in my custom filter.

Any idea why I get the error?And how to fix it?

Comment: can you show a JSON.stringify(result) ?

Comment: Post data in JSON format, not image.

Comment: @dfsq, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's not convenient to deal with images if I wanted to set up a demo to test something.

Answer (score 0):

Add `track by $index` to your ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="sensorData in list.sensorsData | filterByAlert:list.alertTags  track by $index">
```

Comment: track by always needs to go at the end of the expression